# Command line ODBC client tool for windows

Tags: sql, windows, odbc

Is there an equivalent command line ODBC testing tool to isql (provided by ODBCUnix) or iodbctest (provided by iODBC)? 
As i'm building testing framework, I need to avoid a GUI flow, and thus prefer not to use tools like MS ODBCTest.

I'm developing my own sql engine. Also I have an ODBC driver for my database. The client tool needs to be agnostic to the database provider, and work with any DSN registered, as does MS ODBCTest. This way I can compare my sql engine output against any other RDBMS

Comment: What DB platform(s) are you looking at. MsSql has command line, that you can use.  Also, Mysql.

Comment: @Anthony Horne im developing my own sql engine. Also I have an ODBC driver for my database. The client tool needs to be agnostic to the database provider, and work with any DSN registered, as does odbctest.

Comment: Maybe include some of that detail in the actual question - which gets indexed by the search engines.